# Bash/Shell : Reducing Time Consumption

Tags: python, json, bash, shell

I have a python script `domaincheck.py` and a json file `domain.json` were i can make a lookup of any `domainname` and which gives me `name` of the domain queried.

```
#Usage 1 : python domaincheck.py cnn.com 
#Usage 2 : python domaincheck.py bbc.com    

#Result 1 : CNN
#Result 2:  BBC
```

Now, I have a input file `set_3.txt` and which is of about 65000 lines of domains. I wrote a small shell logic to to batch processing.

```
$for i in $(cat set_3.txt); do python domaincheck.py $i;done
```

I ran the script like six hours ago and till now it has processed only around 20,000 domains.

How to do this efficiently and reduce time consumption using Bash/shell? Is there any parallel execution method in bash which I can use to minimize the time for processing?

Comment: Take a look at [GNU parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel).

Comment: Thanks cyrus. Will have a look at GNU parallel method too.

Comment: Be careful -- if you start 65,000 queries at roughly the same time, you will probably overload the capacity of your DNS server.  Try to keep it in batches of 200 or so.

Comment: It's going to be much, much more efficient to do the loop in Python instead of looping in a shell (*or* with parallel, *or* with xargs) at all. Starting Python interpreters is going to be most of your cost here -- and Python has its own parallelism mechanisms present in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

```
$ parallel -a set_3.txt -j+0 -k "python domaincheck.py {}"
```

`-j` numbers of cores, j+0 means num. of parallel jobs equal to num. of cores

`-k` Keep sequence of output same as the order of input

GNU Parallel can make using multicore in parallel. But python process will run every time.

There is inefficiency of process creation overhead.

Anyway it's faster than single process because OS use all cores, and simplest.

And There is another simple way about parallelizing, http://www.parallelpython.com/

Comment: That's a [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html); you want `< set_3.txt parallel ...`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the output to be displayed or to be redirected to the output ?

Either way, try this (for redirect):

```
for i in $(cat set_3.txt)
do
 echo "$i $(python domaincheck.py $i)" >> temp.csv &
 sleep  1
done
```

There might be better ways to do this.  You can even start concurrent python processes (65000, in your case), if you have enough RAM and CPU.

Comment: Yes , I will be redirecting the stdout to a file. Thanks for the logic . Will have to alter my python script for some concurrent execution method.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor -- you want `while read i; do ...; done <set_3.txt`

Comment: With the `sleep 1` there is no way this can take less than 18 hours. In fact, it's probably slower than the original!  But if you take out the `sleep`, you will face other issues.

Comment: oh yes, I didn't think of that though (while and sleep).. my bad... maybe the domain list can be split into 10 files and run concurrently if the machine can handle the load, if that's feasible.

Answer (score 1):

han is right. instead of calling python multiple times which has process creation overhead, use the python code itself to parse the input file and launch multiple threads/processes to do the tasks